# Use request and passport npm login account

Tags: node.js, authentication, request

I am using nodejs for a project,now I want login my account with passport npm,but not from webpage,from request post method,can it be done?

**main code like this:**

```
router.post('/login',function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { return res.json(null); }

        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            //return res.redirect('/'); redirect not work 
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});

router.get('/check',function(req, res, next) {
    request.post({
       url:'http://localhost/login',
       headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
       },
       form:{
       username:'myname',
       password:'mypassword'
    }},function(err,httpRes,body){
        //do here...?
        return res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

When I call "check" with get method and use the correct username/password,I can print out the user data from database in "login" method,but lost the user session when it redirect home page.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not redirecting the user when they GET `/check` because the POST request to `/login` in `/check` is getting redirected itself, not the actual user. Also making internal requests to internal webpages isn't the best solution for logging in. I suggest creating `login()` [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) like so:

```
// Don't forget to set req.body.username and req.body.password when calling login().
var login = function login(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return next(); }

    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }

        return next(null);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

And then calling it appropriately:

```
router.post('/login', login, function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) {
    console.log('We logged in successfully!');
    res.redirect('/');
  } else {
    res.json(null);
  }
});

router.get('/check', function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.user) {
    login(req, res, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      if (!req.user) {
        // No user, do some error handling.
      } else {
        // We have the user, do some custom stuff...
      }

      res.redirect('/');
    });
  } else {
    // User is logged in already, do some other custom stuff...
  }
});
```

You can check if a user is logged in by checking if `req.user` exists.

Comment: Yes,should be use a middleware.but it seems not solve the login issue.How to login in "check" request use username and password that PASSPORT nom need.just simply make up a req.body?

Comment: Yes,I add the code "req.body.username = myname;req.body.password=mypassword" in "check" request before call login function,and it works.thanks

Comment: Cool, glad it worked. I'll update the answer to specify that you have to add those two variables to `req.body` in `/check`.